# Override TestNG Test name when using a provider and omit parameters

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

Have the following Sample code ... when running tests (and in reports), I would like the Test Names to be set to the description field provided by the provider (really it's any String).

... however, even when extending from ITest, it seems like all the provider parameters get appended to the TestName, what I want is the description only.

So actual test name should be "TestName1" instead of "TestName2[1](TestName2, 2, 2, 4)" .. which is what is showing up in XML reports, and test.aftertest name.

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TestNgProviderExample implements ITest{

    @Test(dataProvider = "summationProvider")
    public void testProvider(String description, int number1, int number2, int sum) {
        Assert.assertEquals(sum, number1 + number2);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "summationProvider")
    public Object[][] summationData() {
        Object[][] testData = {{"TestName1",1,2,3},{"TestName2",2,2,4}};
        return testData;
    }

    private String reportedTestName = "";

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void testData(Method method, Object[] testData) {
        reportedTestName = testData[0].toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getTestName() {
        return reportedTestName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I created an issue about the problem: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1382

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply running a `@Test`-annotated method without parameters can solve it.
Instead of parameters my solution uses class fields and a constructor `@Factory` method.

```
public class TestClass implements ITest {

    protected String description;
    protected int firstNumber;
    protected int secondNumber;
    protected int sum;

    @Test
    public void testProvider() {
        /**
         * Minus or plus here to make it fail or pass.
         */
        assertEquals(this.sum, this.firstNumber - this.secondNumber);
    }

    @Factory(dataProvider = "summationProvider")
    public TestClass(String description,
                     int firstNumber, int secondNumber, int sum) {
        this.description = description;
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "summationProvider")
    public static Object[][] summationData() {
        Object[][] testData = {{"TestName1", 1, 2, 3}, {"TestName2", 2, 2, 4}};
        return testData;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTestName() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

Output with formatting from my IntelliJ Idea:
[image]

Of course, it is possible to make the `@Factory` instantiate another class, not the same `TestClass`.

And if you have 40 separate variables from parameters and want to keep it short... Add a class that would be a holder for those parameters, e.g. `ParametrizedInput`. It would at least make it possible to hide all those instance variables.
You can place `description` in the second class as well (in that case `ThreadLocal<ParametrizedInput>` usage would be advised).
The second class will grow with parameters, but since it is a plain old Java object, it shouldn't break anything in test.
If you don't want to set all those variables, another idea would be to access parameters lazily in tests.
Following expert's ([Krishnan Mahadevan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679824/krishnan-mahadevan)) advice I figured out that the name with a method can be set with a `@BeforeMethod`- and `@AfterMethod`-annotated methods.

```
public class TestClass implements ITest {

    protected static ThreadLocal<String> description
            = new ThreadLocal<>();
    protected ParametrizedInput input;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(Method method) {
        this.description.set(this.description.get() + " " + method.getName());
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(Method method) {
        this.description.set(this.description.get().substring(0,
                this.description.get().length() - method.getName().length()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testProvider() {
        assertEquals(this.input.getSum(),
                this.input.getFirstNumber() / this.input.getSecondNumber());
    }

    @Test
    public void anotherTestProvider() {
        assertEquals(this.input.getSum(),
                this.input.getFirstNumber() - this.input.getSecondNumber());
    }
    @Factory(dataProvider = "summationProvider")
    public TestClass(String descriptionString, ParametrizedInput input) {
        this.description.set(descriptionString);
        this.input = input;
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "summationProvider")
    public static Object[][] summationData() {
        Object[][] testData = {{"TestName1", new ParametrizedInput(1, 2, 3)},
                {"TestName2", new ParametrizedInput(2, 2, 4)}};
        return testData;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTestName() {
        return this.description.get();
    }
}
```

Parameter Holder class:

```
public class ParametrizedInput {

    private int firstNumber;
    private int secondNumber;
    private int sum;

    public ParametrizedInput(int firstNumber,
                             int secondNumber, int sum) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    public int getFirstNumber() {
        return firstNumber;
    }

    public int getSecondNumber() {
        return secondNumber;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! .. is there any possible way to do this with out Factory ? it can get difficult with the codebase that I'm dealing with.

Comment: Why can it get difficult? If there are too many data providers or tests in one class, simply split it. I use factories and do not have so many problems with them ;)

Comment: Inherited codebase .. Some thing like 40 parameters, would prefer not to define add 40 instance variables ... but it seems like you solution is the only way, and there's no way around this ... Unless I'm missing something ?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz - The implementation that you shared is best suited for Test classes that have exactly one `@Test` method in them. When you add up more `@Test` methods to the same test class, it again gets exposed to the same problem.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan, do not understand fully, but you are usually right. If I access class instance variables with getters there are no parameters and there is no problem.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz - Maybe this blog post of mine would elaborate what I am talking about https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/pretty-printing-with-testng/
In a nutshell, when you have 2 or more  `@Test` methods, then TestNG ends up using the same `ITest` implementation for showing their names.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan, thank you. I have updated my answer so that many `@Test` methods can be handled.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan, the OP wanted to hide all parameters from reports. In order not to hide method names I have added a `@BeforeMethod`- and an `@AfterMethod`-annotated methods,

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz - Have you tried running the test methods in parallel :) I think the results will be interesting. You may want to make the `this.description` field as a `ThreadLocal` variable to ensure that we take care of this condition as well.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan, don't `@*Method` annotated methods run in the same thread as test methods?

Comment: yes they do. But if you notice, now all of them are basically attempting to overwrite the same class data member at the same time. So the thread that last runs (in concurrent execution model) will update it to the last readable value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137832/discussion-between-grzegorz-gorkiewicz-and-krishnan-mahadevan).

Comment: Simplified my answer.