# How we can name the test case dynamically when using data provider

Tags: java, selenium, testng, dataprovider

How we can  name  the test case dynamically when using data provider, for example:

If I have a login test case, and I want use data provider for different user name and password, where each user represent a country, how I will have the output of test failed or pass but with different test case name for instance I should have like this:

```
loginTestUSusername pass
loginTestINusername pass
loginTestJPuserName pass
```

Note that the name of the method is loginTest, and the appended `USusername,INusername,JPusername` are the test data from the data provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps below:

**Step# 1:**

Create a custom annotation in a separate file (ie: **SetTestName.java**)

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SetTestName {
    int idx() default 0;
}
```

**Step# 2:**

Create a base class implementing **ITest** interface of **TestNG** (**TestNameSetter.java**).

```
public class TestNameSetter implements ITest{
    private String newTestName = "";

    private void setTestName(String newTestName){
        this.newTestName = newTestName;
    }

    public String getTestName() {

        return newTestName;
    }


    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void getTheNameFromParemeters(Method method, Object [] parameters){
        SetTestName setTestName = method.getAnnotation(SetTestName.class);
        String testCaseName = (String) parameters[setTestName.idx()];
        setTestName(testCaseName);
    }
}
```

**Step# 3:**

Use your DataProvider like in the code snippet:

```
@DataProvider(name="userData")
 public Object[][] sampleDataProvider()
 {
  Object[][] data = {
    {"loginTestUS_Username","loginTestUSPass"}, 
    {"loginTestIN_Username","loginTestINPass"},
    {"loginTestJP_UserName","loginTestJPPass"}
  };

  return data;
 }



 @SetTestName(idx=0)
 @Test(dataProvider="userData")
 public void test1(String userName, String pass)
 {
     System.out.println("Testcase 1");
 }

 @SetTestName(idx=1)
 @Test(dataProvider="userData")
 public void test2(String userName, String pass)
 {
     System.out.println("Testcase 2");
 }
```

That's all. Now, you will see your test name changed accordingly in the console.

Follow the link below for your query. I hope, you might get your desired answer here:

http://biggerwrench.blogspot.com/2014/02/testng-dynamically-naming-tests-from.html

Comment: Thank you very Much, its work and show up in my html report as different test case

Answer (score 0):

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42727782/4280359) for reference.

1. Use those string like `"USusername"` etc. in your data provider (like `"TestName1"` and `"TestName2"` in the example) together with some other test data (like those numbers in example). Pass this name as argument to your `@Factory` annotated method.
2. Make the test class implement `ITest`. Use the test name variable in return statement.
3. You can split it up the way as in the example.